# Query and sort by model's belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model Book which has many copies.

Copy belongs to Book and also belongs to School, which has many copies.

I would like to query for books that associate with a school and sort by number of copies and I am a bit lost on how to do this with the current relationships.

A book model contains the data for the copies, like title, author, etc, and the copy is like the physical record of the book.

Any help in organizing this relationship would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait, do schools have books or do schools have copies of books? It sounds like, according to your data structure, schools might somehow have both, which I have a hard time making sense of.

Comment: probably not written very well, but i guess a school has many copies through books

Comment: Schools only have copies, which have books. You see one book can be used across many schools, so in order to make a relationship between books and schools, I think I would need a separate model for the making the join.

Comment: so the copy has the `school_id`? And you want to give the method a certain `school id` or do you want to query it for all schools?checkout my updated query

Answer (score 1):

```
Book.joins(:copies)
    .where("copies.school_id = ?", school_id)
    .order("COUNT(copies.id)")
```

Comment: This would depend on `books` having a `school_id`, which is something I think may not make sense...although I'm not sure that I completely understand the situation, so I could be wrong.

Comment: now when i read again i see that i have maybe (probably) misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 0):

I can't venture to give you an answer in ActiveRecord, but here's what might be a plausible answer in SQL:

```
  SELECT book.name,
         school.id,
         COUNT(copy.*) number_of_copies
    FROM book
    JOIN copy on copy.book_id = book.id
    JOIN school on copy.school_id = school.id
GROUP BY school.id,
         book.name
ORDER BY number_of_copies
```

This depends on your tables being structured in a certain way. It seems to me that schools would not have books, but rather *copies* of books, so I think the `copy` table should have a `school_id` and `book_id` and neither the `book` nor `school` tables should have foreign references.